# Nested associations, how to prepare variables for views, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, associations

Running Rails 3.1.3...

I'll use a simple example of nested associations (not sure if this is correct term). Basically I'm modelling databases - each database has its own tables and each table has its own columns:

```
class Database < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tables
end

class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :database
  has_many :columns
end

class Column < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table
end
```

My question is, say I want to display a database's tables and columns in a view, what would be a good way of bundling this data before passing it to the view. Basically, what would my controller and view look like?

I've come up with the following, but I would be surprised if there is not a much better way of doing this:

**My controller:**

```
class DatabasesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @database = Database.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @tables = @database.tables
    @columns = @database.tables.columns
  end
end
```

**My view:**

```
Database: <%= @database.database_name %><br />
<% @tables.each do |table| %>
  Table: <%= table.table_name %><br />
  <% table.columns.each do |column| %>
    Column: <%= column.column_name %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've also played around with using this in the controller:

```
@database = Database.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:tables => [:columns])
```

However trying to access the table and column names from @database has driven me mad.

---

**UPDATE:**

Typically, I have spent many hours trying to figure this out and shortly after I post here, I think I get it. Thanks for the suggestion miked - this worked for me. Also, if I amend my own method by using the first! method it works as follows:

**Controller:**

```
def show
  @database = Database.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:tables => [:columns]).first!
end
```

**View:**

```
Database: <%= @database.database_name %><br />
<% @database.tables.each do |table| %>
  Table: <%= table.table_name %><br />
  <% table.columns.each do |column| %>
    Column: <%= column.column_name %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  Thanks for pointing out the use of .first on your final sol'n - I will update my solution too.  Without it, the reference in the view would throw an undefined method error when the view tries to access the association(s). Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this actually looks okay to me, though you don't need the @tables and @columns in the controller unless you are really using them for something in the view.

controller:

```
class DatabasesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @database = Database.find(params[:id], :include=>{:tables => [:columns]}) #eager load
    #or: @database = Database.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:tables => [:columns]).first #eager load
    #or: @database = Database.find(params[:id]) #queries will be executed in the view
  end
end
```

view:

```
Database: <%= @database.database_name %><br />
<% @database.tables.each do |table| %>
  Table: <%= table.table_name %><br />
  <% table.columns.each do |column| %>
    Column: <%= column.column_name %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```